# How to compare arrays in my case?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mapping

I am trying to do a mapping in my app.

I have something like

```
$scope.newProducts = ['123','456','789']

$scope.products = [{'id':'123'}, {'id':'121'}, {'id':'678'}, {'id':'789'}];
```

I want to be able to identify `new product` in my `products` array.

I have something like

```
$scope.newProducts.forEach(function(id){
    //not sure what is the best way to find new product id in $scope.products
})
```

I need to identify the `new product id` in `products` array. I wonder what the best way is to do it. thanks for the help!

Comment: This structure `$scope.products = {'id':'123', 'id':'121', 'id':'678', 'id':'789'};` doesn't make any sense.  You're defining an object with duplicate properties.  There will be only one value for that property on the actual object.  Do you mean for there to be an array of ids here somewhere?

Comment: @jfriend00 you were right. please see the updated questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a `isNew` flag on the new products.

```
$scope.products.forEach(function (product) {
    if ($scope.newProducts.indexOf(product.id) > -1) {
        product.isNew = true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a library like [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) which makes these type of operations quite simple.

```
_.each(products, function(item){
    if (_.contains(newProducts, item.id )){
        console.log(item);
    }
});
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fxQCusT2kJ3VL1b7SIIP?p=preview)